# Split list of promises to groups. Execute all promises in group parallel and groups in sequance

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

**What I do:**

I'm crawling the web, the way I do it is that I have got a list of website links and create a promise from each (the promise is basically a crawler). And I do it in sequence so for example if I have 10 links I will crawl the first link, wait for it to finish, crawl second link, etc.

**What I need:**

What I'm trying to achieve is to group my promises. Each group will run in parallel but list of groups will run in sequence.

So for example I have 10 links, and I will create 10 promises from them.
After that, I will split promises into groups with max 3 promises per group.
After that it should crawl first 3 (as they are first group), wait for them to finish and then run 4th, 5th 6th as they are second group etc.

**What I tried:**

I created a method to split promises:

```
export function splitPromises<T>(promises: Promise<T>[], maxPerItem: number): Promise<T>[][] {
  const splitPromisesList: Promise<T>[][] = [];
  let currentSplit: Promise<T>[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
    currentSplit.push(promises[i]);

    if (currentSplit.length === maxPerItem || i === promises.length - 1) {
      splitPromisesList.push(currentSplit);
      currentSplit = [];
    }
  }

  return splitPromisesList;
}
```

After that method which will use that splitting and call promises:

```
async function crawler(links: string[], page: Page): Promise<MyData[]> {
  const list: MyData[] = [];

  const crawlPromises = links.map(async (link, index) => {
    try {
      const newPage = await page.browser().newPage();
      const detail = await crawlLink(link, newPage);
      await newPage.close();
      return detail;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return null as MyData;
    }
  });

  const groupedPromises = splitPromises<MyData>(crawlPromises, 3);
  let results: MyData[] = [];

  for (const group of groupedPromises) {
    results = await Promise.all(group);
    const filteredResults: MyData[] = results.filter((detail) => detail !== null) as MyData[];
    list.push(...filteredResults);
  }


  return list;
}
```

**What are my issues:**
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but it executes all promises at once, not by groups.

Comment: You cannot "run" or "call" a promise. A promise represents a result, and you already run **all** your tasks at once when you call `links.map(…)`. Use an array of functions instead.

Comment: @Bergi is right. Change your code in a way that you return a function for each mapped link instead of executing the code directly. Like this `links.map((link, index) => async () => {try{...}catch{...}})`.
Afterwards  add `const groupPromises = group.map((func) => func())` right before your `await Promise.all(group)` call and change this call to `await Promise.all(groupPromises)`. With this implementation you start crawling the pages for 3 links in parallel and all the other link promises should not be fulfilled yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the promise has been created, the work is already in flight. `await`ing the promises in batches won't delay the work. You instead need to batch the *creation* of the promises.

A function for splitting an array into chunks is still useful, but you need to make it work on an array of strings, not just an array of promises:

```
export function splitArray<T>(array: T[], maxPerItem: number): T[][] {
  const splitList: T[][] = [];
  // ... basically the same implementation as before, with different variable names
  return splitList;
}
```

And then you need to chunk the `links` and create your array of promises from just that one chunk. You'll then wait for the chunk to finish before moving on to the next chunk.

```
async function crawler(links: string[], page: Page): Promise<MyData[]> {
  const list: MyData[] = [];

  const chunks = splitArray(links, 3);

  for (const chunk of chunks) {
    const crawlPromises = chunk.map(async (link, index) => {
      // .. same as before, except we're mapping over `chunk` instead of `links`
    });
    const results = await Promise.all(crawlPromises);
    const filteredResults: MyData[] = results.filter((detail) => detail !== null) as MyData[];
    list.push(...filteredResults);
  }

  return list;
}
```